# Vertical Align Top for Lightning Datatable Subclass

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have extended LightningDatatable:

```
export default class DispatchConsoleDataTable extends LightningDatatable {

   static customTypes = {

       smartCalendarCell: {
           template: calendarCell,
           standardCellLayout: false,
           typeAttributes: []
       }
   };
}
```

using this template:

```
<template>
    <c-dispatch-console-calendar-cell data-navigation="enable" cell-value={value}></c-dispatch-console-calendar-cell>
</template>
```

and this cell definition:

```
<template>
    <template for:each={cellArray} for:item="cell">
        <lightning-layout key={cell.Header} multiple-rows="true">
            <template if:true={cell.IsPM}>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6"></lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
            <lightning-layout-item size={cell.Size}>
                <lightning-formatted-text class={cell.Class} value={cell.Header}></lightning-formatted-text>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <template if:true={cell.IsAM}>
                <lightning-layout-item size="6"></lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
            <template if:true={cell.HasFromTo}>
                <template if:true={cell.IsPM}>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6"></lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
                <lightning-layout-item size={cell.Size}>
                    <lightning-formatted-text class={cell.Class} value={cell.FromTo}></lightning-formatted-text>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <template if:true={cell.IsAM}>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="6"></lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout>
    </template>
</template>
```

Everything is working fine except I would like to override the default vertical alignment of the cells, which seems to be center alignment:

[image]

Question:  How do I change the vertical alignment for my custom cells to be "top"?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything in particular? For instance, what if you add `<lightning-layout vertical-align="start"` to your cell definition?

Comment: Yes I've tried all the usual suspects.  No luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with `lightning-datatable` but it's worth an Idea on [IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).

Here's why:

- there's no attribute that exposes vertical alignment
- Shadow DOM prevents you from modifying this with CSS in your custom cell. You wouldn't be able to bypass the two LWC wrappers (`lightning-primitive-custom-cell-factory` and `lightning-primitive-custom-cell`) and other elements that are in the way to get to the parent `th` element.

[image]

Comment: Well that's a shame.  Thanks for the info, POZ.

Answer (score -3):

@Dave C Try using padding css style, please find below which i tried.

[image]

For the purpose of explaining, i pushed the cell value to top and did not align center. In order to achieve the above, i gave `padding-bottom:50px` to push my content to the top of the cell. Also not sure if you tried `margin:auto; top:0`.

[image]

Let me know if the above solution helps!

Comment: you cannot simply do that in the context of a namespaced component in LWC, as the title states "Lightning Datatable Subclass" the shadow boundary wont allow you to do this. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Sunil, but glls is right.